# Intercept EventEmitters with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm building a node.js module and I wish also to test it with Jasmine.

Let say my module look similar to this:

```
var myModule = function (foo, bar) {

  // Begin a workflow
  var workflow = new (require('events').EventEmitter)();

  workflow.on('test', function () {
    var greet = greet();
    return greet;
  });

  workflow.emit('test');

};

function greet () {
  return "Hi!";
}

module.exports = {
  myModule: myModule
};
```

How can I test my module with Jasmine targeting all my Events I emit?

Something like this:

```
var myModule = require('../myModule.js');    

describe('My Module test', function () {

  it('should get greet value', function () {
    myModule.on('test', function () { // "test" as I wrote in myModule
      expect(myModule.greet).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I accomplish this using proxyquire: https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire

In your test file:

```
var proxyquire =  require('proxyquire');
var mockEvents = {};
var myModule = proxyquire('../myModule.js', {
  events: mockEvents
});

describe('My Module test', function () {
  beforeEach(function() {
    mockEvents.EventEmitter = function () {};

    mockEvents.EventEmitter.prototype = {
      on: function () { },
      emit: function () { }
    };

    spyOn(mockEvents.EventEmitter.prototype, 'on');
    spyOn(mockEvents.EventEmitter.prototype, 'emit');
  });

  it('should get greet value', function () {
    myModule()
    expect(mockEvents.EventEmitter.prototype.on).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test');
    expect(mockEvents.EventEmitter.prototype.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test');
  });
});
```

You can also use a spy as your mock EventEmitter, etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, can I ask a more detailed example? I'm new to the unit testing world and it would be nice to understand it better...

Comment: Not sure if that example fully works, as I just wrote it inline. But you should read this: http://jasmine.github.io/2.5/introduction And also the docs on proxyquire.

Comment: I will test it as soon as I can and let you know. Thanks

Comment: I tested it and played a bit with it but without success, I always receive the following error: `Expected spy on to have been called with [ 'test' ] but it was never called.` I have a `console.log('in test');` called successfully when I run `myModule()` within the test.

Comment: Yeah. You'll probably have to adjust. I updated it to fix that particular issue, but there may be others.

Comment: I tried it even before your changes but the error is always the same and I don't really know how to handle it...

Comment: The error means that the specified functions aren't being called. I think the reason is that you're using new: `var workflow = new (require('events').EventEmitter)()` but the mock I provided wasn't a constructor. I'll adjust it.

Comment: Thanks for your edit but it still fire the same error...  If this could help I can change the `var workflow` to be `this.workflow` even if I don't really like the idea...

Comment: Yeah. I never use the `new` keyword in JS, personally. I kind of am with Douglas Crockford on that one. But I think you've got what it takes to move forward. `proxyquire` is how you inject dependencies into a commonjs module. Jasmine's spies (e.g. `spyOn`) are how you check to see if something was called. If I were you, I'd start with the absolute most basic module and get tests passing, (e.g. a "hello world") and then incrementally add complexity, keeping tests passing the whole way.

Comment: It is what I did. But as soon as I tried to use private functions I was not able to test anymore. Using Event Emitters should help to test it better and code is also cleaner. But I don't know the correct way to go ahead...

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that `greet` is not really exposed and is therefore not accessible in the tests. Here are some ways to handle this:

1. Add it to the prototype chain to make it accessible (this is what I have done below).
2. Expose the function in the `module.exports`. This could be wrapped in a `process.env.NODE_ENV !== production` to exclude it from production.
3. Not expose it but test the event emitter functionality and impact of the function (this is probably not ideal).

To achieve what you want, you could monkey patch the functions and test that they have been called and test the result of `greet` individually:

**MyModule.js**

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var MyModule = function (foo, bar) {
  // Begin a workflow
  var workflow = new EventEmitter();

  workflow.on('test', function () {
    return this.greet();
  }.bind(this));

  workflow.emit('test');
};

MyModule.prototype.greet = function () {
  return "Hi!";
};

module.exports = MyModule;
```

**MyModule-tests.js**

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

describe('MyModule', function () {
  it('emits an event upon construction', function () {
    // Monkey patch
    var originalEventEmitterOn = EventEmitter.prototype.on;
    EventEmitter.prototype.on = jasmine.createSpy('on');

    // Create module
    var MyModule = require('./MyModule');
    new MyModule();
    expect(EventEmitter.prototype.on).toHaveBeenCalled();

    // Reset
    EventEmitter.prototype.on = originalEventEmitterOn;
  });

  it('calls greet upon construction', function () {
    var MyModule = require('./MyModule');

    // Monkey patch
    var originalGreet = MyModule.prototype.greet
    MyModule.prototype.greet = jasmine.createSpy('greet');

    var myModule = new MyModule();
    expect(myModule.greet).toHaveBeenCalled();

    // Reset
    MyModule.prototype.greet = originalGreet;
  });

  it('returns "Hi!"', function () {
    var MyModule = require('./MyModule');
    var myModule = new MyModule();
    expect(myModule.greet()).toBe("Hi!");
  });
});
```